# How do I open Visual Studio NuGet Package Overview?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I wanted to get back into programming a discord bot. To do so I need to isntall the discord-api form the NuGet Package Manager. But when I try to open it up the button is not clickable.
[NuGet Not Clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vh3P.png)

What might be the reason for that?

(It is checked in the version of Visual Studio that I am using)

-Visual Studio Community 2019

-Console Application

Comment: Did you try to clean your solution and restart your visual studio?

Comment: Is the app still debugging or building? I got just this problem today until I realized ... I had paused the program while debugging

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do you mean by paused the program while debugging? I've not written any code yet. I need to install a package before I can even start writing the code.

Comment: You have to explain what *you* are doing. You posted a very small part of your screen that hides what the project is, what it contains. In VS 2022 that menu item only shows the NuGet manager for the entire solution. The per-project settings require a current project. If you don't have a project yet, or the selected project doesn't work with NuGet, you won't be able to manage packages, either from that menu or by right-clicking on the project. Have you tried right-clicking on your project?

Comment: Are you building a .NET Core or .NET Framework 4.x project? NuGet was developed separately from .NET Framework 4.0 but at the same time. It's not available for older versions at all. The oldest supported .NET Framework version, 4.6.2 will work fine.

Comment: I've suspected the .Net version to be the problem because I am using .NET Core 3.1. But when I try installing a newer version it just doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't, but .NET Core 3 reach End Of Life 2 weeks ago. The Long Term Support version now is .NET 6, supported until 2024. Discord and all other package authors will start dropping support for 3.1 sooner or later. The `Discord.NET` package supports both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 6.

Comment: What kind of application did you build? Console? Web? Worker? How did you create it? From the project wizard? Did you open an existing solution? Or did you open a folder directly? You should be able to add the package from the command line by running `dotnet add package Discord.Net` in the project's folder

Comment: Should I try installing .NET 6 for it to work?

Comment: It works. The question is what's going on on your machine. You should install .NET 6 because it's the oldest supported .NET Core version

Comment: I created a Console Application Project

Comment: You can create a .NET Core 3.1 project in VS 2022. When I create a project from the Project Wizard the `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution` menu is always active, no matter what file I select in the Solution Explorer. Right clicking on the project node also shows a `Manage Nuget Packages` option in the context menu. In both cases I can search for and add the `Discord.Net` package

Comment: (I'm using VS 2019 should I update?) 


By runnig `dotnet add package Discord.Net` I get:
[image](https://imgur.com/cWrrumv)


By runnig `dotnet --info` in cmd I get:
[image](https://imgur.com/gYbpZzf)


By running `dotnet --list-sdks` in cmd I simple get nothing.

Comment: This means that no .NET Core SDK was installed. How was Visual Studio installed in the first place? [All of the .NET-related workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community?view=vs-2019#net-cross-platform-development) include a version of .NET Core.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well I don't know... I tried VS 2022 after and could use .Net 6 and 7 but the NuGet Package Manager was still not working. So I switched to Eclipse/Java which I have used before and know better. Now everything works and I've got a working bot. Still thanks for all the help 

Comment: What does Eclipse and Java have to do with NuGet and Visual Studio? Which aren't broken and don't have the problems you described? This isn't up for debate - hundreds of thousands of developers use them. NuGet is mandatory for every project type these days and simply works out of the box.